# Mostrar datos de GridView en asp.net C# pero no mostrar su clave primaria

Tags: asp.net

Quiero mostrar los datos de una tabla en SQL Server en un gridview sin que se muestre la clave primaria que los representa, es decir, utilizo una consulta que me extrae [id], [nomActivo], [descripcion] pero mostrar sólo [nomActivo], [descripción] en la página ASP  (cada activo tiene un checking para selecionar uno o varios) y que cuando el usuario le de al botón de guardar, poder obtener el [id] que le corresponde a cada activo, esto para llenar una tabla de uno a muchos...

No sé si la forma como lo estoy haciendo es la correcta o si hay otra manera de hacerlo.

No se si se puede hacer algo similar a cuando se utilza un comboBox donde eligo que datos mostrar pero en realidad obtengo el ID de cada dato mostrado en el comboBox y no el propio dato cuando lo guardo.

Answer (score 0):

Debes configurar el gridview:

1. Autogeneratecolumns=false
2. Vas a editar columnas en las opciones de diseño del Gridview
3. Agregas tantos boundfiel como elementos en el select de la consulta con la que vas a llenar el gridview tengas
4. En cada boundfield le asignas un HeaderText que corresponde al encabezado del gridview y en datafield el nombre de la columna a la que corresponde en la consulta es decir, si en tu consulta tienes "select nombre as NombreRecurso from recurso" en datafield irá NombreRecurso

Una vez hayas hecho esto debes llenar el Gridview y será suficiente.